# Is it possible to do URL redirect in AWS Route 53?

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, redirect, nginx, amazon-route53

My domain is www.example.com in AWS Route 53.

I want following redirects to happen by configuring in AWS Route 53

```
example.com --> www.example.com/abc
www.example.com --> www.example.com/abc
example.com/abc --> www.example.com/abc
example.com/anyRubbish --> www.example.com/abc
```

Conditions:
No .htaccess or writing redirect rules in Apache/Nginx web server.

Is this possible?

Comment: There Is One Way you can redirect and that creates s3 bucket and use it as static website hosting and redirect wherever you want with help of cname in route 53 but your URL is not subdomain but directory I have no idea how you can achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

No, Route53 is just a DNS service. It simply returns an IP address for a given domain name. You have to map paths and generate redirects somewhere else.